# Passing data from an adapter to its own activity not to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an activity contains a horizontal recyclerView which works fine and below that there are some textViews which I need to set them by clicking on each item in that recyclerView. The way that I did it is to use intent to send "item position" from adapter and restart the whole activity to get related information from that position, but it costs me send one more and redundant request to server while activity is restarted. Any alternate approach for this?
here is some parts of code:
in UserActivity:

```
 if (userViewModel.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    viewHolder.rView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    viewHolder.rView.setAdapter(new AddFormsListAdapter(
                            userViewModel.getResult(), R.layout.item_rv_request, MyApplication.getAppContext()));
                    intent = getIntent();
                    if (intent != null) {
                        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                        if (extras != null) {
                            int position = extras.getInt("ITEM_POSITION");
                            viewHolder.tvCity.setText(userViewModel.getResult().get(position).getCity());
                        }
                    }
```

and in adapter:

```
 holder.setItemClickListener(new ListItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserAddRequestActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ITEM_POSITION", position);
            context.startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            ((UserAddRequestActivity) view.getContext()).finish();

        }
    });
```

Comment: create an interface for onclick item of recycler view in activity, or create a method in your activity and call the method using the context of the activity

Comment: you don't need to do that, put this horizontal listener  as inner class then access it, ex:  class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {.......}

Comment: nice to here it. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add inner class like this, then change elements u want in main class without reloading with parameters

```
class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
.........
.......

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     dochanges u want in main class
}

}
```

Comment: nice to here it. cheers. @seeya please upvote this as well if it helps